# Examples of polygons drawn by path vs polygon in SVG

Tags: svg

I would like to learn SVG, and am trying to learn how the same image can be rendered by using either the point (with polygon) or by dynamically by paths (path).

I would like a few examples of the SAME polygon (triangle, square, and pentagon are enough to begin) in BOTH SVG polygon AND SVG path, so that I can compare the code.   I can find individual images drawn by either, but none that are the SAME.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It's trivial: You can basically take the `points` attribute of a polygon and turn it into a path's `d` attribute by prepending `M` and appending `z`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <polygon points="20,20 100,20 100,100 30,110"/>
  <path        d="M20,20 100,20 100,100 30,110z" fill="green" transform="translate(100,0)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Visual comparisons FTW.

Answer (score 5):

> Both can create shapes.
>
> `polygon` will automatically close the shape for you (by returning to the first point) after drawing at least three sides, and is composed of a series of connected straight lines, which means it [is not as versatile as `path`].
>
> `path`s can use straight OR curved lines, and do not auto-close the shape for you. `path` is probably the most powerful basic shape element in SVG.

Lightly edited from [*What is the difference between polygon and path? (Answer)*](https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/176785/what-is-the-difference-between-polygon-and-path#:%7E:text=Both%20can%20create%20shapes.,it%20does%20not%20scale%20well.&text=Path%20is%20probably%20the%20most%20powerful%20basic%20shape%20element%20in%20SVG.)

Comment: Polygon and Path will scale the exact same for a series of points. That statement should come with further explanation.

Comment: Edited for clarity (seems like the source is referring to versatility rather than scale)