# Convert SVG polygon points to path?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am looking for a function that can convert something like:

```
var points="270,328 270,376 342,376 342,368 358,368 358,320 314,320 298,336 278,336"
```

into the SVG format for **paths**, I have seen [this question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717190/convert-svg-polygon-to-path), but I get an error :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerSVGElement' of undefined. This is because I am putting my var points into that function, which is not designed for that, I think it needs the full xml or something.

Any suggestions are great, especially to force illustrator to export paths instead of polygons!

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var points="270,328 270,376 342,376 342,368 358,368 358,320 314,320 298,336 278,336"

var p = points.split(/\s+/);
var path = "";
for( var i = 0, len = p.length; i < len; i++ ){
    path += (i && "L" || "M") + p[i]
}

console.log( path )
=> M270,328L270,376L342,376L342,368L358,368L358,320L314,320L298,336L278,336
```

Comment: I am getting this sometimes: M630,352L630,306LLLLL704,314L704,356L718,356L718,384L702,368L646,368L646,360L638,360L638,352LLL, and arent they supposed to end with a 'z'?

Comment: Updated my answer. Also, you are only supposed to add a z if you want to close the path.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But this could be more readable.  
`path = 'M' + points.replace(/\s+/g, 'L');`

Comment: @YuriyYakubskiy I would suggest to use `split`/`join`, so you can ommit the `g`-modifier. Also, don't forget to trim the points before replace: `'M' + points.trim().split(/\s+/).join('L');`

Comment: In fact you can also prepend `M` and omit the `L` lineto command tokesn so: `M ${points} Z` would also do the trick. A `<polygon>`also requires a `z` close path command - otherwise you'd have a `<polyline>`