# Can't get GSAP MorphSVG to work

Tags: svg, gsap

I've set up a simple SVG with two polylines and am trying to morph between them using GSAP's MorphSVG. https://greensock.com/morphSVG

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 960 560" style="enable-background:new 0 0 960 560;" xml:space="preserve">
    <polyline id="plainLine" class="st0" points="298,279 387.5,279 469.2,279 596,279"> </polyline>
    <polyline id="roofLine" class="st0" points="297.6,282 385.8,257.9 469.2,279 596,279"> </polyline>
</svg>
```

Based on the documenation, it seems it should be as simple as:

```
TweenLite.to("#plainLine", 1, {morphSVG:"#roofLine"});
```

But try as I might, nothing is happening...

Here's a fiddle with my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/o48g3h0b/

Answer (score 2):

Morph SVG Works with Paths instead of polygon, rect & circles you need to convert the polygon into Paths first
Morph can itself convert the rect, polygons & circles to Paths but for complex objects it behaves clingy

To Convert the Rect, Polygons, Circles use Raphael Technique already mentioned in this thread
[Convert Polygon to Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717190/convert-svg-polygon-to-path)

Check my [Pen](http://codepen.io/thebunny/pen/vKjBjE) i have created the same effect

`<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 960 560" style="enable-background:new 0 0 960 560;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="plainLine" d="M298,279L387.5 279 469.2 279 596 279" style="stroke: red;stroke-width:8;fill:none"/>
<path id="roofLine" d="M297.6,282L385.8 257.9 469.2 279 596 279" style="stroke: red;stroke-width:8;fill:none;"/>
</svg>
</body>`

One more thing to your notice MorphSVG plugin is membership required plugin i would suggest using snap svg & animate path method for the morphing of svg.

Answer (score 0):

I see what it is...MorphSVG is a "Club Greensock" (i.e. paid) plugin I haven't paid for. No wonder.