# Get outer boundary path or coordinates of an overlapping svg/vector path

Tags: algorithm, svg, vector, html5-canvas, vector-graphics

Suppose we have an array of points that can be used to draw an SVG/vector path.

```
const points = [[1,1], [3,4], .....];
```

[image]

I want the path or coordinates of the outer boundary of this path as shown below.

[image]

There is a [way to find union of overlapping polygons](https://github.com/w8r/martinez) but in my case I have a single overlapping path and not multiple overlapping polygons.

Comment: you may try [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) where you add half stroke width to the bounding box width and height and rest half stroke width from the x and y

Comment: I don't need the bounding box of the path. I need the outer part of the path after removing the inner parts.

Comment: copy it to canvas and read off the pixels from canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Paper.js Boolean operations](http://paperjs.org/examples/boolean-operations) might be helpful.

The `unite()` method can merge single or multiple shapes to remove any overlap:

```js
paper.install(window);
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvasPaper");
const polygonPoints = [
  [38.2, 26.3],
  [24.4, 25.7],
  [18.4, 41],
  [23.6, 61.9],
  [40, 64.4],
  [50.1, 50.5],
  [39.1, 38.8],
  [30.2, 45.1],
  [49.3, 61.5],
  [59.2, 60.9],
  [71.3, 54.7],
  [74.2, 38.5],
  [68.7, 27.8],
  [60.4, 20],
  [46.3, 25.5],
  [45.8, 38.3],
  [61.2, 41.6],
  [72.3, 28.4],
  [69.9, 20],
  [62.1, 14.3],
  [43.6, 14.3],
  [38.2, 26.3]
];

// create an render initial polygon
const mergedPolygon = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
mergedPolygon.setAttribute("fill", 'none');
mergedPolygon.setAttribute("stroke", '#000');
svg.appendChild(mergedPolygon);
// convert polygon points to path commands
let polygonD = polygonToPath(polygonPoints);
mergedPolygon.setAttribute("d", polygonD);


function unite() {
  paper.setup("canvasPaper");
  let path = new Path(polygonD);
  // merge/unite path
  let united = path.unite();
  // get svg d 
  let unitedData = united
    .exportSVG({
      precision: 3
    })
    .getAttribute("d");

  united.strokeColor = "black";
  united.scale(2, new Point(0, 0));

  //update svg 
  mergedPolygon.setAttribute("d", unitedData);
}


//convert polygon point array to path d 
function polygonToPath(points) {
  let d = `M ${points[0][0]} ${points[0][1]}`;
  for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    d += `L ${points[i][0]} ${points[i][1]}`;
  }
  return d + "z";
}
```

```css
canvas,
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.0/paper-full.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <button type="button" onclick="unite()">Unite Path </button>
</p>
<svg class="svgunite" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
</svg>
<canvas id="canvasPaper" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

**Conversion steps**

1. we convert the polygon point array to path commands, using a helper function `polygonToPath(points)`. (See [also: Convert SVG polygon to path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717190/convert-svg-polygon-to-path))
2. we create a paper path node by `new Path(polygonD)`
3. overlaps are removed by `path.unite()`
4. `exportSVG()` will return svg commands of the united/merged path